# Extract json using scrapyd crawler

Tags: python, json, scrapyd

how can i extract schema.org only from this webpage code?  it's in json and it gives me hard time. i only need the information that gives me the schema.org link. When i crawl i want to extract schema.org from each website and put it in a file.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Scutece Huggies Ultra Confort BOX 5, Girl, 12-22 kg, 105 buc",
        "url":"http://www.emag.ro/scutece-huggies-ultra-confort-box-5-girl-12-22-kg-105-buc-5029053546919/pd/DPS0Q7BBM/",
    "sku":"DPS0Q7BBM",
    "brand": {
        "@type": "Brand",
        "name": "Huggies"
    },
    "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "seller": "eMAG",
        "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    },
    }
</script>
```

UPDATE:

already try this:

import json

jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())

tells me: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: what do you mean you want to extract "schema.org"? For the example, what is the expected output? What code do you have written?

Comment: every time i crawl a page i want to see it has a http://schema.org/. Basically i want to extract only those 2 info: "@context": "http://schema.org" and "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",